# button works only once

Tags: jquery

i have a problem with my jquery code, a have a list of buttons witch changing display from none to block of some div and "save" button witch changing display from block to none, when i'm clicking again on same button from the list of buttons display is not changing, nothing happens, WHY ??

http://gidzior.net/svg/pom01.html panel on the right is the '#right-panel li' and the red button is the 'div.save'

buttons from '#right-panel li' should open a window and button 'div.save' should close it and then '#right-panel li' should open it again but shouldn't close it

```
$('#right-panel li').each(function(e){
        var i = $(this).index() + 1;
        $(this).click(function(){
            if(i<10){
            i = "0"+i;
        }
            $('#pom01par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').css('display', 'block');
            $('#pom02par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').css('display', 'block');
            $('#pom03par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').css('display', 'block');
            $('#pom04par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').css('display', 'block');
            $('#pom05par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').css('display', 'block');
            $(this).css('background','#adff84');
            $('.par'+i+'table').css('background','#adff84');
            return false;
        });
    });


    $('div.save').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().css('display','none');
    });
```

**UPDATE**

well i found an error, when i'm clicking button with number from 1 to 9, script put 0 befor number 1-9 and the index is 01,02,03 ..., when i'm clicking it again the index is 001, 002, 003,... and so on, how do I set the index remained the same all the time ?? 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09

Comment: can u paste the link or screen shots??

Comment: http://gidzior.net/svg/pom01.html

panel on the right is the '#right-panel li' and the red button is the 'div.save'

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want first click to show, second click to hide and so on, use `.toggle()` instead:

```
$('#pom01par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').toggle();
$('#pom02par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').toggle();
$('#pom03par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').toggle();
$('#pom04par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').toggle();
$('#pom05par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').toggle();
```

Otherwise, with your current code the first click will show the elements. Second click will also show the elements, but they're already visible - what exactly you **expect** to happen?

Comment: @gidzior OK. What is the new question? My answer still stands and you didn't give any new information.

Comment: buttons from '#right-panel li' should open a window and button 'div.save' should close it and then '#right-panel li' should open it again but shouldn't close it

Comment: What is the save button? I don't understand the language there, sorry.

Comment: save button is the red one in the window with radio buttons, i updated lang and now it is save

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written only changes `display: none;` to `block`, not back.

I would recommend using:

```
$('#pom01par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').toggle();
```

and

```
$(this).parent().hide();
```

instead.